# HttpContext.Request.Form.Keys is empty when HttpContext.Request.HasFormContentType = true

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This was working 2 days ago and now it's not and I cannot figure out why.  I am submitting form data via ajax:

```
    var mData = 'item=' + itemid + '&action=' + action;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/Home/Ajax",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        data: mData,
        success: function (data) {
            //Do Something
        }
    });
```

I have a method that process the incoming post:

```
            if (HttpContext != null && HttpContext.Request.HasFormContentType)
            {
                foreach (var key in HttpContext.Request.Form.Keys)
                {
                    QueryParams.Add(key, HttpContext.Request.Form[key]);
                }
            }
```

When the data is posted, `HttpContext.Request.HasFormContentType` is equal to true however, `HttpContext.Request.Form.Keys.Count` is equal to 0

I get no errors or anything. Any help or insight as to what is going on would be greatly appreciated.

This is a dotnet core 2.2 mvc web app.

Comment: Why are you using such code? In an action, you can get the form parameters as action parameters or even a strongly-typed object. If you can't, it doesn't mean that MVC binding is broken, it means that something is wrong. In this case, there are no form parameters. The current code can't be tested at all because it depends on HttpContext

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working demo like below:

1.View:

```
<script>
    var mData = 'item=' + 1 + '&action=' + "aaa";
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Ajax",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        data: mData,
        success: function (data) {
            //Do Something
        }
    });
</script>
```

2.Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Ajax(int item,string action)
{
    if (HttpContext != null && HttpContext.Request.HasFormContentType)
    {
        foreach (var key in HttpContext.Request.Form.Keys)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

3.Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are sending query data, not form data. Try sending it in a form like:

```
{
 item: ...,
 action: ...
}
```

Edit: Actually I was a bit surprised that it works while sending `raw` type of data and then passing in the query-like string. But the mearly fact that it works it doesn't mean it is a proper way of doing things. Foe example if You try to send API request from Postman (which I tried to reproduce Your error) I wasn't even able to perofrm such a thing as Postman asked me for key value pairs and interpreted a given query as a one key. Besides sending js object is more simpler that building a string.

Comment: You are right, it's not really a form post, but ajax make it a post.  I have been using ajax this way for many years without a problem.  I have other dotnet projects still working with the same method of posting.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the issue of `HttpContext.Request.Form.Keys is empty`.

I just removed the `.aspx` extension from the request page and now the problem seems to be resolved for me.